# Sending data stream to multiple URLs using org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient

Tags: java, apache, ibm-midrange

Firstly, let me say I not a java programmer, I am a programmer on the IBM Iseries. However, I've been tasked with changing a current java application that currently sends a stream of data to one URL that will allow that same stream of data to be sent to multiple URLs based on a properties file. Our java app runs on the Iseries and we are using the org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient class to send the data and the response is processed. Everything works great right now, but I wanted to see if anyone could point me in the right direction to complete this task.

Essentially, I need to send the same block of data to multiple URLs within the same thread or instance. I'm not sure if its possible or the best way to try to complete this. So, is there a way to create multiple instances within the same thread that will send the same data stream to multiple URLs? Before you start commenting I will say again that I am not a java programmer and I wasn't even sure how to phrase the question.

Added code sample:

```
public class Replication_CC implements TextProcessor {

public static String VERSION = "v2014.1.0";
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Replication_CC.class);
String url;
int retries = 1;

public Replication_CC(Properties p) {

    super();
    url = p.getProperty("url");
    log.info("Service URL set to " + url);
    retries = PropertiesUtil.getOptionalIntProperty(p, "retries", 1);
    log.info("Retries set to " + retries);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    log.info("Replication " + VERSION);
    log.info("Initializing...");

    Properties p = PropertiesUtil.loadProperties(Replication_CC.class.getResource("/Replication_CC.properties"));
    DQServer server = new DQServer(p, new Replication_CC(p));
    server.run();
}

public String process(String request) throws Exception {

    long processStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String response = null;
    for (int i=0; i<=retries; i++) {
        try {
            response = send(request, url);
            if (response!=null) break;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("Error processing:  " + e.getMessage());
            if (i<retries) {
                log.warn("Trying again (retry " + (i+1) + "...");
            }
            else {
                log.error("Giving up on this transaction.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    long processFinished = System.currentTimeMillis();
    log.info("Request was processed in " + (processFinished-processStart) + "ms.");
    return response;
}

public String send(String request, String url) throws Exception {
    log.debug("Creating request...");
    HttpClientParams params = new HttpClientParams();
    params.setParameter("http.useragent", "http-api / Replication");
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(params);
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod(url);
    /*
    List<NameValuePair>  params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    for (String key : globalRequest.keySet()) {
        params.add(nvp(key, globalRequest.get(key)));
    }
    */
    post.setRequestBody(request);

    // Log the request
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        post.getRequestEntity().writeRequest(baos);
        baos.close();
        log.debug("HTTP Request: \n" + StringUtils.repeat("*", 100) + "\n" + "Content Type: "
                + post.getRequestEntity().getContentType() + "\n" + "Content Length: "
                + post.getRequestEntity().getContentLength() + "\n" + "Request Headers: "
                + ArrayUtils.toString(post.getRequestHeaders()) + "\n" + "Request Params: " + baos.toString() + "\n" + 
        StringUtils.repeat("*", 100));
    }

    try {   
        log.info("Sending request...");
        int responseCode = client.executeMethod(post);
        //log.debug(String.format("Http Response Code [%s]", responseCode));
        log.debug("Http Response Code [" + responseCode + "]");

        if (responseCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            String charset = post.getResponseCharSet();
            log.debug("Response Character Set [" + charset + "]");
            /*
            byte[] body = post.getResponseBody();
            String response = new String(body, charset);
            */

            String response = IOUtils.toString(post.getResponseBodyAsStream());
            log.debug("Response Body: \n" + response);
            return response;
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception(post.getStatusLine().toString());       
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        log.error(ioe);
        throw ioe;
    }
    finally {
        post.releaseConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just execute multiple requests that are mapped to different URLs?

Comment: This should be straight forward.  Can you include a short sample of the existing code to get started?

Comment: I have added a sample of the code in question.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to include multiple URL's in the existing url property separated by a unique character.  I chose "|" (pipe) in this example because it's highly unlikely to see a pipe in a normal url.

Java identifies methods by name and parameter signature.  We can use that to our advantage by adding a `String url` parameter to the existing process method and creating a new `process(String request)` method that will split and iterate over the url's.  The only downside is that it will only return the last response to the `DQServer` class.

```
public String process(String request) throws Exception {
    String response;
    for (String u : url.split("\\|")) {
        response = process(request, u);
    }
    return response;
}

public String process(String request, String url) throws Exception {

    long processStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String response = null;
    for (int i=0; i<=retries; i++) {
        try {
            response = send(request, url);
            if (response!=null) break;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("Error processing:  " + e.getMessage());
            if (i<retries) {
                log.warn("Trying again (retry " + (i+1) + "...");
            }
            else {
                log.error("Giving up on this transaction.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    long processFinished = System.currentTimeMillis();
    log.info("Request was processed in " + (processFinished-processStart) + "ms.");
    return response;
}
```

---

The complete sample is available on GitHub [Gist](https://gist.github.com/jamesallman/8422098).

Comment: Thank you for you replies I truly appreciate them. The response will be needed from each url the data is sent to. Would it be a difficult task to make that happen?

Comment: @danwilk The problem is the `DQServer` class will only call the `process` method one time and it expects a single response.  Changes would have to be made to that class to handle multiple responses.